# Просмотр памяти Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

Если для Linux инструмент (или возможность в какой-либо ide) для просмотра оперативной памяти процесса, наподобие инструмента просмотра памяти в Visual Studio?[image: Этот инструмент в VS13]

Comment: Любой графический отладчик или IDE (для C++) это могут. QtCreator, CodeBlocks, ddd,...  Уточните требования.

Comment: А можно ручками https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux

Comment: Просмотр в GUI режиме памяти по адресам

Comment: GDB вам в помощь(отрывок памяти и имя файла случайные):
dump ihex output_file.txt 0x200000000 0x200000350